# How to align POS Printing using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, android, pos

I have been trying to print a particular div with ng-repeat using a pos bluetooth printer using Javascript.

```js
function sendToQuickPrinterChrome(){
   
    var qtylength = document.getElementById("totalQtyLength").outerText;
        var objDiv = document.getElementById("div_print").outerText;
        var dt = document.getElementById("Date").textContent;
        var qty = document.getElementById("totalQty").textContent;
        var total = document.getElementById("total").textContent;
        var order =  document.getElementById("order").textContent;
    
        var orderNo = document.getElementById("orderNo").textContent;
        var _orderNo = "<CENTER> <BOLD>" + orderNo.trim() + "<BR>";
        var tokenNo = document.getElementById("tokenNo").textContent;
        var tokenNoVal = "<CENTER> <BOLD>" + tokenNo + "<BR>";
        var orderdet = "<CENTER> <BOLD>" + order;
        var a = "<CENTER> <BOLD>" + dt;
        var totalVal = "<CENTER> <BOLD>" + total;
        var quantity = "<CENTER><BOLD>" + qty.trim();
       

        var objDiv = "<CENTER><Big>Company <BR>" + "<CENTER> <BOLD>Order Summary <BR>" + _orderNo + tokenNoVal + a +"<BR>"+ order + qty.trim() + totalVal;
    var textEncoded = encodeURI(objDiv );
    window.location.href="intent://"+textEncoded+"#Intent;scheme=quickprinter;package=pe.diegoveloper.printerserverapp;end;";
    
}
```

Order is a div with the product name and price. When it is to be printed in the POS reciept printer, there is a misalignment. We are using  Quick printer android app to print as it is an old POS printer. The app is used in a Tablet